# How to make an executable game accessible for users to play online

Tags: html, web, exe

There's a  little `.exe` file which contains a game I want to make available on a website *(pure HTML)*, but I don't know how to do it.

What I want to achieve is: when clicked, users shouldn't have to install it but be able to play it on the site.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question doesn't appear to be related to programming. However what you appear to want is basically impossible.

Comment: You need to make your game content playable in browser rather than serve an exe file and have it somehow run in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't use or run executables with html.** Html and js can not modify directly contents in your PC and use system functions, they can do what they are allowed to by the browser, that communicates with the system and restricts some functioning.

That is why they can be considered "virtual" - they run on the browser that take care of their parsing and viewing.

For the same way you can't either embed it, since embedding requires the ability to run it.

Comment: ok,but can i upload this setup file to any website?

Comment: You can upload the file so they'll download it, you can't make it run in browser.

Comment: It is possible to run an emulator in the browser that runs `.exe` files, such as [Boxedwine](http://www.boxedwine.org/).